# Bluetooth plugin for ios in Phonegap

Tags: ios, plugins, cordova

Currently in the `phonegap plugins`, I can find bluetooth plugin for 
Android only.

Do we have bluetooth plugin for `iOS`.

If there is , please let me know.

If not,how should we enable and disable bluetooth through phonegap in ios.

Answer (score 1):

For Android there is: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Bluetooth

For iOS there is **not**: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS

Apache Cordova Documentation API Reference there is **not**: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/index.html

**If not there then where? :(**

I would also like to know how to bluetooth, pair devices, multiplayer, hack the world :)

Answer (score 0):

From PhoneGap v2.7.0 seems this plugin is available for both Android and iOS (via BLE)
https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial

It also appears this plugin is available on PhoneGap Build